# Sign on with a single key rather than username / password?

Tags: login

I find username / password combinations to be cumbersome.

Is there a way to sign on to unix-based systems using a single passphrase like "iamMe%3"?

Obviously there would have to be some specialized application which would run instead of the standard login. I think there is some API called PAM that controls all this stuff. The question is whether there is a canned PAM-based solution that allows username/password credentials to be replaced with single passkey.

Comment: SSH login? Console/virtual terminal login? logging into X?

Comment: you could configure a GUI login greeter to automatically log a certain user in, or you could set a blank password for the user, but then there's nothing to stop someone from accessing your files as you.  autologin might be suitable for a kiosk-style setup in some contexts, but be aware of the security tradeoffs in such a system.

Comment: What if different users have the same password? How do you identify, which user do you want to log in? Note: I think it is a *good question*: the explanation, *why is it impossible*, is useful.

Comment: @peterh Obviously the passwkey system would have to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

As @peterh mentioned, if multiple users select the same password, the system has no way to know which user to authenticate.

You could of course set a blank password for a given user, assuming the security policy permits this, as usernames are unique. The downside of course is that your account has no password.

Automatic login is, by default, almost as bad. You still have a password, but tasks that require no further authentication, such as deleting the contents of your home directory, are accessible to everyone.

---

One alternative that has been convenient for me, on a system where I am the only user, was to:

- Configure `getty` to automatically log me in on the first VT,
- Configure `bash` (my default shell) to start GNU `screen` if it is not already inside a `screen` session, and
- Include a command to lock the screen in my `.screenrc`

A similar approach would work for a graphical environment; simply replace the lock provided by `screen` with some kind of X11 display lock program.

This method isn't entirely *secure* — an attacker with physical access could simply edit these configuration files.

---

For SSH access, you can avoid usernames and passwords entirely, by setting up public-key authentication and specifying the appropriate username in you SSH configuration file.

Comment: I was hoping there was a standard approach. The case in which two users have the same passkey should be impossible because the system should enforce unique passkeys. Setting blank passwords is not practical because the usernames are public.

Comment: @TylerDurden so ... when I try to change my passkey, it gets rejected and now I know the passkey of somebody else on the system? Awesome!

Comment: @muru In most passkey systems, the passkey is system generated, not user chosen, and the system generates an unguessable sequence of characters.

Comment: @TylerDurden Using a system-generated pass(word|key) feels like a bad idea to me. You're unlikely to get something memorable, and the system needs some way of providing you the new pass. Every online service I've used that sends generated passwords includes a warning (some even a requirement) to change the password after first login. You could work around both these issues by using smart cards, but then you're using a "something you have" instead of a "something you know", and require hardware support